# React-Native Oauth2 Firebase SpringBoot

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, react-native, oauth-2.0

I have been developing an app using React-Native and Spring Boot. Its time to implement Oauth2. I initially decided to develop spring boot for Oauth2 JWT integration for Authentication and Authorization. Now I am thinking why don't I go for FireBase only for Oauth2 integration (Internal and Social login).

Note: I just want to keep only Authentication details in Firebase, Rest all will follow conventional SpringBoot + MySql based Rest services style application. 
1) I will persist all User details in conventional RDBMS 
2) I want to keep only User Auth Credentials in Firebase
2) And Further User Identity and Rest end points protection will be based on JWT

Please advise me pros and cons. Recommend me a better design and Help me make a better decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pro -> solid Auth system built for you, so long as you are willing to glue pieces together.

I would recommend looking at this article: http://pscode.rs/firebase-and-spring-boot-integration/

source code: https://github.com/savicprvoslav/Spring-Boot-starter

Its a bit outdated but a good starting point

Comment: Many thanks Julio, will go through the code. Yes I prefer to glue pieces rather than reinventing wheel.